# How can exchanges activate users' XLM addresses?

Tags: accounts

Which method should be used to activate a user's XLM account to send them XLM?
We need to do it with someone's account that does not belong us.

Answer (score 0):

For native asset (XLM), some exchange will determine whether the account exists in the Stellar network, if it exists, use the [Payment Operation](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations/#payment) to send the asset, if it does not exist, use the [Create Account Operation](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/start/list-of-operations/#create-account) to activate the account and send the asset.